# linux bash script kill process and start it again after kill

Tags: linux, bash, kill-process

Im running several chrome browsers on my computer with different profiles. Profiles are named like "prof1" "prof2" and "prof3". Now I need to make a script which kills specific chrome process and restarts it again.

I cannot use killall command cause I need to be specific which chrome browser I want to kill and if I use kill command script exits after kill command.

I have tried something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

kill -9 `ps ax | grep -i prof1 | awk '{print $1}'` &
sleep 2

export DISPLAY=:0.0

/usr/bin/chromium-browser --restore-last-session --user-data-dir=/path/to/prof1/ %U &
```

This script works nicely but after kill command it exits (saying "Killed") and the browser never gets started again. Kill command does not have any "quiet" option. There is no point of trying 2>&1 cause "Killed" output comes from terminal not from stderr/stdout. I have tried "set -e" and many other things but no luck.

Any help/tips anyone ?

Comment: Does `export DISPLAY=:0.0; /usr/bin/chromium-browser --restore-last-session --user-data-dir=/path/to/prof1/ %U &` work alone?

Comment: Don't use `ps | grep` use `pgrep`. I suspect you may be finding and killing yourself.

Answer (score 0):

What you can use is `pkill`'s `--full`/`-f` flag, which will match the whole command line:

```
$ sleep 1d &
[1] 23335
$ pkill -f 'sleep 1d'
[1]+  Terminated              sleep 1d
```

And you shouldn't use [`kill -9`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement#I.27m_trying_to_kill_-9_my_job_but_blah_blah_blah...).